# Is there a better name for a "spherical annulus"?

Tags: geometry, analysis, terminology

For example, the set $\{x\in\mathbb{R}^d: 1\leq|x|\leq2\}$. For $d=2$, I'd call this an annulus. What do we call it in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In three dimensions, this is called a [spherical shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_shell) and the name is relatively common.

In higher dimensions, you can say "hyperspherical shell" or "$d$-dimensional spherical shell", see e.g. [this article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2002944) for an example of the usage.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.